# AWS API Gateway/Lambda Using External API and ExpandoObject in C#

Tags: c#, aws-lambda, async-await, webapi, expandoobject

I'm try to use the New York times Books API, I have to use a ExpandoObject to return it in my Function handler but I'm Having a hard time Figuring out how to convert the information into an ExpandoObject. right now when I try to run it in the mock lambda test tool it prints out "Failed to find method FunctionHandler" instead of the books object. any suggestions would be great.

```
namespace newyorktimes
{
public class Function
{
    public static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    static async Task<ExpandoObject> FunctionHandler(string input, ILambdaContext context)
    {
        
        string newYorkApi = string.Format("https://api.nytimes.com/svc/books/v3/lists/current/hardcover-fiction.json?api-key=Kz6lZl5qkn6WrGSwQLing2HW7SsjTP0p");
        WebRequest requestObjGet = WebRequest.Create(newYorkApi);
        requestObjGet.Method = "GET";
        HttpWebResponse responseObjGet = null;
        responseObjGet = (HttpWebResponse)requestObjGet.GetResponse();

        dynamic Object = new ExpandoObject();
        Object.List = responseObjGet;

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(newYorkApi);

        return Object;
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: so you are using `WebRequest` and `HttpClient` at the same time? Get rid of the `WebRequest` code. All of it. It's legacy. Under the `client.GetAsync` code, add `var myDynamicObject = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<dynamic>();` Then you can read from it: `var value = myDynamicObject.whateverPropertyYouWantToRead;`

Answer (score 0):

Like the comments say you should not use `HttpClient` together with `WebRequest` - the latter is deprecated. Here's an example of how you could do it:

```
public class Function
{
    public static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    static async Task<ExpandoObject> FunctionHandler(string input, ILambdaContext context)
    {
        
        string newYorkApi = string.Format("https://api.nytimes.com/svc/books/v3/lists/current/hardcover-fiction.json?api-key=Kz6lZl5qkn6WrGSwQLing2HW7SsjTP0p");
        
        dynamic Object = new ExpandoObject();

        using var response = await client.GetAsync(newYorkApi);
        Object.List = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<dynamic>();

        return Object;
    }
 }
```

or just return the result straight away without creating `ExpandoObject` first:

```
return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<dynamic>();
```